# Does updating the MacOS to 10.15.4 affects profile signing

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

After updating the MacOS to 10.15.4, not able to build the project with xcode, error " provisioning profile doesn't include signing certificate"

Answer (score 0):

Even though it doesnt make any sense at all for this to happen , Iv Seen it happen to multiple and yes my guess is as good as yours .Following the MacOs Update you have to /Already have update XCode to Xcode 11.0 and following this , your developer profile has to be updated with a new one for Xcode version 11.0 and forward (or create a new one done delete the previous one) and then add it to your xcode and update the profiles and that did it for me . once it is created it will say xcode version 11.0 and latest